# No Position but accepted without parameter name

Tags: powershell, command-line-arguments

Dang, I am running into all sorts of argument passing issues today. As I understand it, if a parameter doesn't have a position assigned, it is a name only parameter, and should only work if the name is provided. However, with this code

```
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param(
        [string][Alias("sL")] $setList,

        [string][Alias("aS")] $applySet,
        [string][Alias("cS")] $conformSet,

        [Parameter(ValueFromRemainingArguments = $true)][Object[]]$extraParameters = @()
    )

Write-Host "sL: $setList"
Write-Host "aS: $applySet"
Write-Host "cS: $conformSet"
Write-Host "X:  $extraParameters"
```

and a command line of  **... -file "Test-Arguments.ps1" -set:Set Junk**
Junk gets assigned to $applySet, even though the name is not provided. Am I misunderstanding this functionality as well?

Comment: `[CmdletBinding(PositionalBinding=$false)]`

Comment: Oh Huzzah! I think me and DuckDuckGo need to look into [CmdletBinding()] for some other answers too.

Comment: Hrrm, other than the fact that it was introduced in PS3 and I have to support PS2. Very frustrating. :( And, so far as I can tell there is no way to conditionally use PositionalBinding in PS3 and not in PS2, with a single script. And with the horror that is .NET versioning moving to compiled code might not help much either. Back to the drawing board.

Comment: Then one of parameters should be explicitly positional. You can mark `ValueFromRemainingArguments` parameter with `Position`.

Comment: Ah, so setting the cruft parameter as 0 with no position on the other named ones will force them to behave? Interesting workaround. I like it!